# How to set selected item in combobox in Silverlight 4?

Tags: vb.net, silverlight-4.0, combobox, selecteditem

In Silverlight 4, I have a combobox which is binded with a list of State objects( which has StateId, StateCode,StateName properties) and I am showing StateName as the options of combobox.

Now I want to select the option "Michigan" which is stored in a string variable called "strSelectedState". How do i do this ?  I tried setting SelectedValuePath property as strSelectedState. But doesn't work. How can I proceed?

Answer (score 0):

SelectedValuePath binds the value of the SelectedValue property to that path on your object. So if you set it to "StateName" then when you do myListBox.SelectedValue, you will get back the StateName of the selected State rather than the whole State object.

If this is what you want to do, you can set SelectedValuePath to "StateName" then set SelectedValue to "Michigan" and it should work select for you.

Otherwise leave SelectedValuePath blank and set .SelectedItem to a refrence to the State object for Michigan. How you grab that reference will depend on details you have not provided. A LINQ query will work though if nothing else.